# Chef vault - error accessing vault item during kitchen converge

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

Here is the call I am making in my recipe:

```
mypassword = chef_vault_item("passwords", "default_pass")
```

Here is the error I am getting when running a kitchen converge on this recipe:

```
         Net::HTTPServerException
     ------------------------
     404 "Not Found"
```

What do I need to do to allow kitchen to access this vault item?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you configure `data_bags_path` or put your files in the default location (`data_bags/`). The error mentions a server so you aren't use the default solo-based provisioner, but it would help to state which you are using.

Comment: I am using the chef_zero provisioner.  I was able to get it to converge successfully by adding a data_bag under ./test/integration/default/data_bags in my cookbook directory.  I'm still not able to retrieve the value in a recipe though.  How do I access the value?

Answer (score 2):

I was informed by someone at Chef that chef_vault_item does not support encrypted data bags.  You need to add dummy values as unencrypted data bags for testing purposes so your unencrypted passwords are not being checked into version control.  The unencrypted data bag needs to be created in your chef repo under:

```
cookbooks/<cookbook name>/test/integration/default/data_bags/<vault name>/<item name>.json
```

in order for kitchen to successfully converge

Comment: that worked for me.. I would also suggest adding this line to the `.gitignore` file... `test/integration/default/data_bags/*`